# OLE Error Message

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce, ole

I write a program in C#.Net 2010 in .Net Framework 4.0 Client Profile with SQL Server CE 3.5 SP2 using ADO.Net. I've packed my App by Advanced Installer and included prerequisites: SQLServerCe 3.5 SP2, .Net Framework 4.0 Client and windows installer 3.1 in the installation bootstrapper. I use Win 8 Pro and have no problem installing and Running the program, but when it is installed on another PC running Win XP, It shows "OLE Error Message" upon starting the application (after installing successfully). What can be the cause and how may I solve this? (There is no interaction with the database on main form load).
Here are the complete code for Main Form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;

namespace StudentLoanArchives
{
    public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
        public frmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void خروجToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("آیا مطمئن هستید؟", "خروج از برنامه", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2, MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading);
        if (dr == DialogResult.Yes) Application.Exit();
    }

    private void عملیاتاولیهToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string createTable = "CREATE TABLE Bank (bankName nvarchar(20) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL)";
        DataBaseClass.MessageShow(DataBaseClass.ExecuteSQL(createTable), "عمليات با موفقيت انجام پذيرفت", "در انجام عمليات خطا رخ داد");
        createTable = "CREATE TABLE Student (studentNo nvarchar(12) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, studentFName nvarchar(50), studentLName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL)";
        DataBaseClass.MessageShow(DataBaseClass.ExecuteSQL(createTable), "عمليات با موفقيت انجام پذيرفت", "در انجام عمليات خطا رخ داد");
        createTable = "CREATE TABLE Loan (loanNo nvarchar(20) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, loanAmount nvarchar(15) NOT NULL, loanDate nvarchar(10), studentNo nvarchar(12) NOT NULL)";
        DataBaseClass.MessageShow(DataBaseClass.ExecuteSQL(createTable), "عمليات با موفقيت انجام پذيرفت", "در انجام عمليات خطا رخ داد");
        createTable = "CREATE TABLE Payment (payNo nvarchar(20) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, payAmount nvarchar(15) NOT NULL, bankName nvarchar(20) NOT NULL, payDate nvarchar(10) NOT NULL, branchCode nvarchar(10), branchName nvarchar(30), loanNo nvarchar(20), payComment ntext)";
        DataBaseClass.MessageShow(DataBaseClass.ExecuteSQL(createTable), "عمليات با موفقيت انجام پذيرفت", "در انجام عمليات خطا رخ داد");
    }

    private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
        DateTime GregDate = new DateTime();
        GregDate = DateTime.Now;
        string month = pc.GetMonth(GregDate).ToString();
        string day = pc.GetDayOfMonth(GregDate).ToString();
        string weekday = pc.GetDayOfWeek(GregDate).ToString();
        switch (month)
        {
            case "1":
                month = "فروردين";
                break;
            case "2":
                month = "اردي بهشت";
                break;
            case "3":
                month = "خرداد";
                break;
            case "4":
                month = "تير";
                break;
            case "5":
                month = "مرداد";
                break;
            case "6":
                month = "شهريور";
                break;
            case "7":
                month = "مهر";
                break;
            case "8":
                month = "آبان";
                break;
            case "9":
                month = "آذر";
                break;
            case "10":
                month = "دي";
                break;
            case "11":
                month = "بهمن";
                break;
            case "12":
                month = "اسفند";
                break;
        }
        switch (weekday)
        {
            case "Sunday":
                weekday = "يك شنبه";
                break;
            case "Monday":
                weekday = "دوشنبه";
                break;
            case "Tuesday":
                weekday = "سه شنبه";
                break;
            case "Wednesday":
                weekday = "چهارشنبه";
                break;
            case "Thursday":
                weekday = "پنج شنبه";
                break;
            case "Friday":
                weekday = "جمعه";
                break;
            case "Saturday":
                weekday = "شنبه";
                break;
        }

        lblDate.Text = weekday + " " + day + " " + month + " " + pc.GetYear(GregDate).ToString();
        lblTime.Text = pc.GetHour(GregDate).ToString() + " : " + pc.GetMinute(GregDate).ToString() + " : " + pc.GetSecond(GregDate).ToString();
    }

    private void tmrTime_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + " : " + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + " : " + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
    }

    private void بانکToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (new frmBanks()).ShowDialog(this);
    }

    private void دربارهToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("برنامه ی ثبت وام های دانشجویی\nبرنامه نویس : بابک تبیانیان\nشماره ی پشتیبانی : 09358285821","درباره ی برنامه",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information,MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,MessageBoxOptions.RightAlign);
    }

    private void کارکنانToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (new frmStudents()).ShowDialog(this);
    }

    private void وامToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (new frmLoans()).ShowDialog(this);
    }

    private void پرداختToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (new frmPayments()).ShowDialog(this);
    }

    private void جستجوToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (new frmQuery()).ShowDialog(this);
    }

    private void پشتيبانگيريToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (new frmBackup()).ShowDialog(this);
    }

    private void بازگردانیاطلاعاتToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (new frmRestore()).ShowDialog(this);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Pls share some code...

Comment: Suggest you start be adding error trapping to your frmMain_Load, and log/show the full error message - ex.ToString()